# A CSS question on layout horizontally

Tags: css

I am not very familiar with CSS.
I have two `li` elements, each of them contain a label and input field. I would like to style them so that the "li**.input_two**" is located after "li**.input_one**" horizontally. What is the CSS for this?

```
<li class="input_one" id="first_input">
  <label>name</label>
  <input id="the_name" type="text"/>
</li> 

<li class="input_two" id="second_input">
  <label>age</label>
  <input id="the_age" type="text"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the label and the input next to each other then something like this should do this trick:

```
.input_one label,
.input_one input
{
    float:left;
}
```

If you want the two li's next to each other then try this:

```
li
{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different options, depending on:

- Browser compability requirements (i.e, do I need to support IE6)
- Am I willing to specify a width?
- Am I willing to use a clearfix hack or additional markup to clear floats?

Two different options:

```
li.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; /* Hack for IE */
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Or, using floats:

```
li.horizontal {
  float: left;
  width: X%; /* You should always give a float an explicit width
                to avoid browser compability issues */
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `inline-block` hack for IE. I use it all the time and it spares me the huge headache that is floats (sometimes! - they're often very handy)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the display inline property for the list
**#menu li {display:inline;}
**

http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_lists/